# Is it possible execute a function in Prestashop via hooks without creating a module?

Tags: php, hook, prestashop-1.6

I have created this test function (lets call it `ABtest.php`) to send a test message:

```
$host = "http://localhost:8080";
$id = "123";
$email = "mine.mail@gmail.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "mine.mail:mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, TRUE);

function send($host,$id,$email,$ch){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . "/c/" . $id . "/your ID/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "to=" . $email . "&subject=Your ID ");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200 && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 201) {
        printf("An error occured (HTTP %d): %sn", curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE), $output);
    } else {
        printf("Success");
    }
}
```

I would like to place this code into my hook `hookValidateOrder($params)` like this:

```
public function hookValidateOrder($params)
{
    $id = $params['cart']->id;
    $host = "http://localhost:8080";
    $email = "mine.mail@gmail.com";

    // + the rest of my PHP function - see the 1st code block above    
}
```

The problem is that I don´t really know where to place my code. As You can see I am not creating a module, I just want to execute my PHP function via `hookValidateOrder($params)` hook.

Is that possible and where do I place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Not in the proper way.
But you can create an override, in the overrides folder for PaymentModule.php:

```
abstract class PaymentModule extends PaymentModuleCore
{
    public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown', $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false, $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
    {
          // do what you need before

          parent::validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method, $message, $extra_vars, $currency_special, $dont_touch_amount, $secure_key, $shop);

         // do what you need after
    }
}
```

You can also override the any module to do it, or the hook exec and check if it's trying to execute the hookValidateOrder then you place your code.

If you do create an override, don't forget to delete (or rename) the file cache/class_index.php after, to index you new override.